# Ubuntu Server Virtual Host not redirecting properly

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

I have installed Web site on my Ubuntu Server.

The following things are installed on  my Server for running web service. 
1) Apache2
2) PHP5
3) MySql

My main website is redirected to https.

Example (changed for security purpose)

```
    <VirtualHost *.80>
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com
Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

In my default-ssl.conf file i have added the following info.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/example.com/sslcertificate.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/example.com/sslcertificate.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Other settings in above is default.

My main issues comes when i create link for my website like www.example.com it goes to Apache2 Default Web Page and does not go to correct site. If i write in browser directly it works perfect and redirects to https://www.example.com

Answer (score 0):

try to enable your virtual host by command a2ensite default-ssl.conf and disable the default 00-default.conf with command a2dissite 00-defaullt.conf